# ActionScript 3.0 How to call SoundManager to all classes

Tags: actionscript-3

i have 3 classes. the SoundManager.as, MainMenu.as, and OnGame.as.

How can I call SoundManager on MainMenu.as and OnGame.as properly?

I tried:
MainMenu.as:

```
var sound:SoundManager = new SoundManager();
```

OnGame.as:

```
var sound:SoundManager = new SoundManager();
```

but when i turn off the bgmusic on OnGame.as, the bgmusic on MainMenu doesn't turn off.

Sorry for my bad english and explanation. please help me.

//edited

When i call function 'MUTE' from the SoundManager in onGame.as and go back to mainmenu, the bgmusic in MainManu.as is not muted. help please me.

SoundManager.as

```
public static var mVolume:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
public static var mChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
public static var mPosition:Number;
public static var music:Sound = new Sound();

public static var Music:Boolean = true;

public function LOADMUSIC():void {
  if(Music){
    UNMUTE();
  }else {
    MUTE();
  }
    music.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LOADMUSIC);
    mChannel = music.play();
    mChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, ONCOMPLETE);
}
public function ONCOMPLETE(e:Event):void {
  if(DataBase.music){
     UNMUTE();
  }else{
     MUTE();
  } 
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, ONCOMPLETE);
 LOADMUSIC();
}       
public function REMOVE_MUSIC():void{
  try{
    mChannel.stop();
    music = null;
  }catch(e:Error) {}
}
public function MUTE():void {
  mVolume.volume = 0;
  mChannel.soundTransform = mVolume;
}
public function UNMUTE():void {
  mVolume.volume = 1;
  mChannel.soundTransform = mVolume;
}
```

MainMenu.as

```
var sound:SoundManager;
btn_music.addEventListener(TouchEvent:TOUCH_END, MUSIC);

public MainMenu(sound:SoundManager){

  this.sound = sound;

  sound.REMOVE_MUSIC();
  SoundManager.music = new BackgroundMusic01();
  sound.LOADMUSIC();
}
private function MUSIC(e:TouchEvent):void {
  if(SoundManager.Music){
    SoundManager.music = false;
    sound.MUTE();
  }else {
    SoundManager.Music = true;
    sound.UNMUTE();
  }
}
```

OnGame.as

```
var sound:SoundManager;
btn_music.addEventListener(TouchEvent:TOUCH_END, MUSIC);

public OnGame(sound:SoundManager){

  this.sound = sound;

  sound.REMOVE_MUSIC();
  SoundManager.music = new BackgroundMusic02();
  sound.LOADMUSIC();
}
private function MUSIC(e:TouchEvent):void {
  if(SoundManager.Music){
    SoundManager.music = false;
    sound.MUTE();
  }else {
    SoundManager.Music = true;
    sound.UNMUTE();
  }
}
```

There's no problem in changing the background music. When i mute the bgmusic in MainMenu using MainMenu btn_music it works, it works also in OnGame. But if it is from OnGame to MainMenu or MainMenu to Ongame, the bgmusic is not muted . I don't see what's wrong. please help me. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Show the code that actually plays the sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton or some other static (global) access is one easy way to do it. But just to add an alternative solution, [according to some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acjvKJiOvXw) a "better way" is to use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). A simple example of this for your situation could look like this:

First, in your `MainMenu` and `OnGame` class you add a constructor argument (effectively declaring a dependency) of a `SoundManager` instance:

```
public class MainMenu {
    private var sound:SoundManager;
    public function MainMenu(sound:SoundManager){
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}

public class OnGame {
    private var sound:SoundManager;
    public function OnGame(sound:SoundManager){
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}
```

Then in a higher level class, you can create a single `SoundManager` and pass it into the classes that need it:

```
public class Main {
    private var sound:SoundManager;
    public function Main(){
        sound = new SoundManager();
    }
    private function showMenu():void {
        var menu:MainMenu = new MainMenu(sound);
        addChild(menu);
    }
    private function showGame():void {
        var game:OnGame = new OnGame(sound);
        addChild(game);
    }
}
```

The end result is that you have a single `SoundManager` instance being re-used between various classes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you post an example?

Comment: Sorry, I just figured out what's the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it, one of them is to use a Singleton class.
Follow an example:

```
package
{
    public class CustomSoundManager
    {
        private static var _instance:CustomSoundManager;

        public function CustomSoundManager()
        {
            if (_instance)
            {
                throw new Error('CustomSoundManager... use getInstance()');
            }
            _instance = this;
        }

        public static function getInstance():CustomSoundManager
        {
            if (!_instance)
            {
                 new CustomSoundManager();
            }

            return _instance;
        }

        public function soundOn():void
        {
            // your logic to turn the sound on
        }

        public function soundOff():void
        {
            // your logic to turn the sound off
        }
    }
}
```

So, doesn't matter where (e.g. MainMenu.as, OnGame.as), you can use just these methods:

```
CustomSoundManager.getInstance().soundOn();
CustomSoundManager.getInstance().soundOff();
```

Comment: The key here is the `static` instance, making it globally accessible. You could do this with or without the singleton pattern. Alternatively, you could simply pass through the same `SoundManager` instance to `MainMenu` and `OnGame`.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I decided to be clear about several ways to do it. The singleton example is just to illustrate one way, your suggestion is valid as well.

Comment: Indeed, didn't mean to sound like I was critiquing your answer, just adding a thought. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because i can't see what's wrong in my code. Since I only got 1 channel in my game, i used SoundMixer to mute and unmute the music background.

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
...

...
public function MUTE():void {
  mVolume.volume = 0;
  SoundMixer.soundTransform = mVolume;
}
public function UNMUTE():void {
  mVolume.volume = 1;
  SoundMixer.soundTransform = mVolume;
}
```

thanks.